# Apparent memory leak in AsyncLocal<>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, garbage-collection

I've got a massive CI build test suite, well over 3,000 tests. In order to run tests in parallel, I'm making liberal use of `AsyncLocal<T>` objects. Trouble is, since I started doing this, the CI build bot is reaching about 75% complete, and then it bombs out because it's run out of memory. There's no other culprit to point a finger at, other than the newly introduced `AsyncLocal<T>` objects, which are being used to store anything from booleans to complex objects.

I guess I'm abusing the system somehow, and there's some "proper" way to use `AsyncLocal<T>` so that its values get garbage collected once the current context terminates.

It may help to know that before I discovered the existence of `AsyncLocal<T>`, I was attempting to implement this functionality myself using my own class, called `Parallelizable<T>`. That worked using NUnit's `TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.FullName`, but it was slow as molasses, and then I dug into the underlying code and found that was using `AsyncLocal<>`, so I decided to cut out my implementation and change `Parallelizable<T>` to be a wrapper around `AsyncLocal<T>`, so that I would do the minimum violence to my existing tests. And that's when I started getting out of memory failures.

What is the proper way to ensure that these values are GC'd?

Here's my code for `Parallelizable<T>`, FWIW:

```
    public class Parallelizable<T>
    {
        private readonly AsyncLocal<T> _asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<T>();
        private readonly AsyncLocal<bool> _valueSet = new AsyncLocal<bool>();
        private readonly T _defaultValue;
        private readonly Func<T> _defaultFunc;

        public Parallelizable()
        {
            _valueSet.Value = false;
        }

        public Parallelizable(T defaultValue)
        {
            _defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        public Parallelizable(Func<T> defaultFunc)
        {
            _defaultFunc = defaultFunc;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_valueSet.Value)
                {
                    _asyncLocal.Value = _defaultFunc != null ? _defaultFunc.Invoke() : _defaultValue;
                    _valueSet.Value = true;
                }

                return _asyncLocal.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                _asyncLocal.Value = value;
                _valueSet.Value = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I worked around the problem by finding the place in my test fixture base class that made the most intensive use of `AsyncLocal<>` with large objects, and inside the `TearDown()` method made sure to dispose and set the value of the `AsyncLocal` properties to `null`. This solved my problem.

The question, however, remains open: why, when the `AsyncLocal<>` objects themselves were GC'd, did all their values also not get GC'd? That seems to be a bug in the implementation of `AsyncLocal<>`, does it not?

Comment: What test framework are you using? I mean some frameworks like MSTest or VSTest are running each test method in new test class instance hence all non-static members are private for test method and you can run tests in parallel safely without additional tricks.

Comment: @Artur: The build bot is running `dotnet test`.

Comment: But what a framework used to write tests? MSTest? XUnit? NUnit? Any other? If you don't know look at attributes defined above test methods and check their namespaces. `dotnet test` is agnostic to test framework and can run any of them.

Comment: @Artur Oh, NUnit. (I mentioned NUnit in the question :-) )

Comment: Missed this, sorry :)

Comment: AsyncLocal is a convenience wrapper around ExecutionContext, it is not actually where the data is stored and it is not actually disposable. ExecutionContext is also Copy-on-write, so the original instance doesn't know anything about copies of the pointer. I tend to make a class use AsyncLocal in conjunction with IDisposable (e.g. SomeDisposableContext) and make sure to pop the stack/unset the value of the AsyncLocal in the Dispose method. This way, AsyncLocal values are handled cleanly by means of a nice simple to read using statement (very similar to how TransactionScope is used).

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/asynclocal.cs,75